# Why does the first one work and the second one not work? Global and Private variable declaration

Tags: javascript, global-variables

First one. This one works, and I have the var start = new Date(); inside the function.

```
function instance(){
    var start = new Date();
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = start.getTime();
    window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);
}
function start(){
window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);
}
```

And this is the Second one that doesn't work. The var start = new Date() is outside the function.

```
 var start = new Date();
 function instance(){
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = start.getTime();
    window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);
    }
    function start(){
    window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);
    }
```

Even though the second one is a global variable and not a private one, shouldn't it still work? Why do some global variables work while some others don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, functions are variables, just in function form. So, in the second one, the variable `start` and function `start` conflict. If you were to change `function start(){` to `function init(){`, for example, it would work.

This is what allows you to define functions such as

```
var foo = function() {
  ...
}
```

The first one worked because you had a local variable `start` and a global function `start`, resulting in no conflicts.

```
 var start = new Date();
 function instance(){
   document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = start.getTime();
   window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);
 }
 function init(){
   window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);
 }
```